# Install traffic-control layer on the topology in ns3

Tags: c++, queue, simulation, ns-3, traffic-simulation

I want to install the traffic-control layer on my topology below. I tried creating the topology with 3 nodes including node 0, node 1, and node 2. I created 2 p2p links, one between node 0 and node 1, another between node 0 and node 2. I want to measure traffic from node 1 and node 2 sent to node 0. I built as the "traffic-control.cc" file in the tutorial of ns3, however, I see that node 0 has two qdiscs built with node 1 and node 2. I want to have one qdisc on node 0 to measure traffic from other nodes to node 0. How can I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRR0J.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have one qdisc on node 0 to measure traffic from other nodes to node 0. How can I do it?

You can't. Node 0 is connected to Nodes 1 and 2 via two separate P2P links, so there will two different PointToPointNetDevices on Node 0, and so there will be two QueueDiscs.

It's unclear *precisely* what you're trying to measure. Perhaps you can clarify?

If you're trying view all packets going through Node 0's QueueDiscs, you could use one or more of the [TraceSources available on QueueDiscs](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_queue_disc.html). Keep in mind that not all Packets which arrive at a Channel will necessarily makes its way to a QueueDisc – Packets could get dropped due lack of space in the receiving buffer, or simulated corruption.